# How to convert txt to .gz / .z in Linux

Tags: linux

In Linux, how to convert txt to .gz / .z and how to view that converted tar file?

I tried the command below, but it is not working.

```
tar -cf filename.z filename.txt
tar -cf filebane.gz filename.txt
zcat filename.z/gz
```

I get "bad command error".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.Z is typically from `compress`. .gz is from `gzip`. Tar has nothing to do with it. So, something like this would work to convert .gz to .Z

```
zcat <file.gz> | compress - > <file.Z>
```

Or to go the other way:

```
 zcat <file.Z> | gzip > <file.gz>
```

(zcat should understand the format used by compress)

Nowadays, .Z formatted files are rarely seen. That format has been supplanted by gzip and bzip2.

Answer (score 24):

Use [`gzip`](http://ss64.com/bash/gzip.html):

```
gzip filename.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to compress or uncompress the files?

To uncompress, do:
`gunzip filename.gz` results to an uncompressed file `filename` - if the file really IS a gzip compressed file. On most Linuxes, a command `file filename.gz` will tell what the file is. For `.z` use the command `uncompress`

For compressing, you can use `gzip filename.txt` which results to `filename.txt.gz` - if you use `compress filename.txt` you'll get `filename.txt.z`

Answer (score 0):

The tar command does not compress files, it archives them. You can add an option to GNU tar to filter it through gzip. Use `tar czf fimename.tar.gz filename.txt`.

Comment: @kimvais true, but I assumed this was a simple example and the OP would eventually want to tar/gzip multiple files.